# Get annoted method endpoints for JMS

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms, spring-annotations

Is there any way through which I can find all the configured MethodJmsListenerEndpoint's through annotations?

I want to register all these end points with different message listener containers.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "TestQueue")
public void process(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}

//TODO for all connections
foreach(connections){
 //TODO get all  annotated endpoints as prototype
    foreach(endpoint){
      MethodJmsListenerEndpoint processEndpoint = endpoint;
      registrar.registerEndpoint(processEndpoint,containerFactory(connection));
    }   
  }
```

Comment: You can specify on the `@JmsListener` to which container to bind. So why do you need or want to do it manually?

Comment: we have different number connections to be made in each environment and we read the connection details from DB.

Comment: Then hook your db stuff of with a `PropertySource` so that you can use the standard mechanisms of configuration. Which will make your whole config a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your provider you can use configuration customizer bean like HornetQConfigurationCustomizer to manipulate any settings during this bean initialization.

If your configuration should be really adoptive and manageable in runtime then you should not use @JmsListener annotation at all. Just register them all in your code like Spring advises: [JMS](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated-programmatic-registration)

Comment: As of now I am following the same approach just wanted to know that in case there is mechanism to get the  MethodJmsListenerEndpoint which are configured via annotation.

Comment: That is possible by scanning classes for these annotations manually.

Comment: Could you please help with a sample @Pavel Muravyov

Comment: You can look inside JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor souce code specifically in postProcessAfterInitialization() method. 
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really a great help to me.